# Migration form karate 0.9.2 to 0.9.3 Issue - javascript evaluation failed

Tags: karate

1. karate-config.js has `config = karate.callSingle('classpath:token-read.js', config);`
2. Javascript function on **token-read.js** is

```
function fn(config) {
  var userAccessToken = Java.type("com.OAuth2Token");
  config['OAuth2'] = {
    adminUser: function () {
      return userAccessToken.getAuthorizationHeader(name, url, users, "ADMIN");
    },
  };
  return config;
}
```

3. Feature file code is as below

```
Feature: Search data

  Scenario: Sample
    Given url url
    Given path '/data'
    And header Authorization = OAuth2.adminUser() //  Using javascript fun here
    And param request = {"up":10}
    And print response
    When method GET
    Then status 200
```

4. Getting error 
   `javascript evaluation failed: OAuth2.adminUser(), TypeError: OAuth2.adminUser is not a function in <eval> at line number 1`

**Above feature file is working fine with karate 0.9.2 , but not working with 0.9.3**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read this section of the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#restrictions-on-global-variables

Reproducing here:

Non-JSON values such as Java object references or JS functions are supported only if they are at the "root" of the JSON returned from karate-config.js. So this below will not work:

```
function fn() {
  var config = {};
  config.utils = {};
  config.utils.uuid = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' };
  // this is wrong, the "nested" uuid will be lost
  return config;
}
```

The recommended best-practice is to move the uuid function into a common feature file following the pattern described here:

```
function fn() {
  var config = {};
  config.utils = karate.call('utils.feature')
  return config;
}
```

But you can opt for using karate.toMap() which will "wrap" things so that the nested objects are not "lost":

```
function fn() {
  var config = {};
  var utils = {};
  utils.uuid = function(){ return java.util.UUID.randomUUID() + '' };
  config.utils = karate.toMap(utils);
  return config;
}
```

You may need to upgrade to 0.9.5.RC4 for some of this to work, so do try.

Comment: because we changed some things. most users don't over-use JS like you do.

Comment: I tried karate.toMap() using 0.9.5.RC4 its worked with **Scenario** but not worked with  **Scenario outline**