# Karate.toMap() using 0.9.5.RC4 works with Scenario but not Works with Scenario Outline

Tags: karate

1. As suggested in here [Migration form karate 0.9.2 to 0.9.3 Issue - javascript evaluation failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59038178/migration-form-karate-0-9-2-to-0-9-3-issue-javascript-evaluation-failed) i have update karate verions to 0.9.5.RC4.
2. JavaScript fun is like

```
function fn(config) {
  var OAuth2 = {};
  var userAccessToken = Java.type("com.OAuth2Token");
  OAuth2.adminUser = function () {
    return userAccessToken.getAuthorizationHeader(name, url, users, "ADMIN");
  };
  config.OAuth2 = karate.toMap(OAuth2);
  return config;
}
```

3. Feature file with Scenario **worked*

```
  Scenario: <scenarioName>
    Given path 'url'
    And header Authorization = OAuth2.adminUser()
    And def Authorization = OAuth2.adminUser()
    And print Authorization
```

4. Feature file with Scenario outline **not worked**

```
 Scenario Outline: <scenarioName>
    Given path 'url'
    And header Authorization = OAuth2.adminUser()
    And def Authorization = OAuth2.adminUser()
    And print Authorization

    Examples:
      | data |
```

**Error : javascript evaluation failed: OAuth2.adminUser(), TypeError: OAuth2.adminUser is not a function in  at line number 1** , I am having same error with 0.9.3 and moving function to common feature file.

Comment: please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Issue opened : https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/982

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug and will be fixed in the next version: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/982

A workaround is that you re-init the function for each loop under the Scenario Outline:

```
Scenario Outline:
* def OAuth2 = karate.call('classpath:com/utils.feature)
```